# php qr code not generating on server by using google api gives a file with nothing in it

Tags: php, google-api, qr-code

i am using Google API for creating QR Codes but it gives me a file with nothing in it.

my code something like that

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=177x177&chl=Hello World');
move_uploaded_file($file, $path.$file);
```

i tried most of the thing but clueless
please if anyone can help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chart API can create QR for you. but you need some conversion and stick to the basics if you want accurate response from API

i can see you are saving the response in $file can may be a reason to save the name in db.

so why not do it like this

```
$path = $folder_path.$file;
//Note:  you need to give the server path; not the URL
```

but wait... you are creating a QR code for a String saying "Hello World", there is a blank space in the string and you are passing that string with the get method in the url so you need url encoding to encode the spaces to "%20" and so on... for correct url passing.

adding this will solve the problem

```
$my_qr_string = urlencode("Hello World");
```

another thing you are missing is character support for the QR

try using "UTF-8" character encoding to avoid any issues.

for uploading use file_put_contents() method for assured upload

in the end you got

```
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=177x177&choe=UTF-8&chl='.$my_qr_string));
```